# Java HTTP Connection Sniffer

Tags: java, ajax, http, sniffer

I would like to write an application where a Java Programm builds up a HTTP connection to a website and leaves this connection open. Wile the Java Programm is connected to the website it should show me all the AJAX updates which are made to the website without reloading it.

Just like a HTTP sniffer but just without opening a website in the browser but just by have it open through the Java Application.

Can anyone help me with that?

Thank you!

Daniel

Comment: AJAX bases on JavaScript, therefore you need a web-browser for loading the HTML code and executing the JavaScript code. IMHO it makes more sense to use a regular web browser and write an app that remote-controls the web browser.

Comment: Thanks Robert! The thing is that the Java Application should monitor about 50 Websites automatically 24/7 while running on a server. Is that somehow possible?